# What type of authentication to use in a Web API that only receives data from other applications

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt, basic-authentication

I'm developing a Web API using .NET 5.
The API will only be receiving data from services in other applications. No user interface is connected to the API.

I want to implement authentication for my WEB API and I want to know that type of authentication to use for this type of application? Also worth mentioning is that the end user will never enter the credentials used in commmunication with the API.

I've looked at Basic authentication, JWT and OAuth. Which would be the best option in this case and why?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is a good choice for authorization even if you only have other applications talking to your API. The client credentials flow is created for such cases - where there is no user involved. Still, you will have secure access token issued which can be used to access your API.

Even if you decide to go with OAuth and client credentials, you will have to decide how to authenticate the applications (clients). Basic authentication is fine, but if you need something much more secure you can go with mutual-TLS, were the client has to present a certificate to authenticate themselves. mTLS can give you also additional benefit of creating sender-constrained access tokens. So only the client which originally received the access token will be able to use it to access your API (even if someone manages to steal your access tokens, they won't be able to use it).

You can have a look at these articles which talk a bit more about [differences in API authorization and authentication techniques](https://curity.io/resources/architect/api-security/the-api-security-maturity-model/) and about [API security best practices](https://curity.io/resources/architect/api-security/api-security-best-practices/).